# The mouse buttons in the Onboard virtual keyboard prevent the touchscreen from working outside of the Onboard window

Tags: touchscreen, keyboard, accessibility

In Onboard, right after tapping one of the mouse buttons, the touchscreen no longer allows taps outside of the Onboard window. It doesn't allow me to right click anywhere. What could be causing this, and is there a fix? Is there an alternative to Onboard that works better and has a right click button?

Comment: Where's the question? Do you want us to suggest alternative virtual keyboards?

Comment: @Botspot Yeah, I wrote this in the dead of night. I clarified my question and removed irrelevant information.

Comment: Much improved. If you plug in a usb mouse, does it behave as if the mouse is stuck inside a box? (and the walls of the box are the edges of the onboard window?)

Comment: @Botspot No it does not, the mouse moves freely with a regular mouse. Just the touchscreen seems to be affected.

Comment: @Botspot Strange, only certain things are affected though. Right clicking the desktop and title bars of windows works. Right clicking the windows themselves and the LXDE panels however do not. Tapping the right click button and then tapping the desktop works like expected, but tapping inside of, say, firefox, simply ignores the touch input

Comment: That's unfortunate. Since I don't have a touchscreen, I can't help you.